# Awk - Call for a second associated value from file1 after finding a match in file2

Tags: bash, awk

I have a code to read gene names from file1 and find them in file2, then I put them together into a table, my problem is that I need to add another column with the associated "start" value from file1 into the table, but couldn't make it. I've tried, but I don't know much about awk in first place, so any help is welcomed.

The idea of final table is:

```
File1_gen  File2_gen  Start_from_file1  Value_1_from_file2  Value_2_from_file2
```

File 1:
This file has ~70.000 rows and 4 columns; row number, gene name, gene start and gene end, and I just need gene name and start from this

```
        seqnames    start   end
10  Gen_3992149.1   851 900
11  Gen_0011774.1   3899    4043
12  Gen_0011774.1   7628    7692
13  Gen_3993605.1   522 535
```

File 2:
Then, the second file has ~100.000 rows and 3 columns; gene name, and start and end values, and I need the three of them

```
Gen_3993605.1   1   602
Gen_3989779.1   691 1002
Gen_3989835.1   1   993
Gen_0011774.1   1476    1712
Gen_0011774.1   5125    6931
Gen_0011774.1   8838    12313
```

I've already have a pseudocode that do almost all of this

```
awk '
FNR == NR {
  # reading file1
    scaf[$2] 
    co_id[$3]
next
}
{
  # reading file2
  for (i in scaf) {
    id in co_id
    if ( i == $1 )
    print "[1] "  i "\t" "[2] " $1 "\t" "[3] " id "\t" "[4] " $4 "\t" "[5] "$5
    }
       }
 ' Search.txt Genes.txt
```

Resulting something like this:

```
[1] Gen_3993605.1       [2] Gen_3993605.1       [3] 522    [4] 1    [5] 602
[1] Gen_0011774.1       [2] Gen_0011774.1       [3] 3899    [4] 1476    [5] 1712
[1] Gen_0011774.1       [2] Gen_0011774.1       [3] 3899    [4] 5125    [5] 6931
[1] Gen_0011774.1       [2] Gen_0011774.1       [3] 3899    [4] 8838    [5] 12313
[1] Gen_0011774.1       [2] Gen_0011774.1       [3] 7628    [4] 1476    [5] 1712
[1] Gen_0011774.1       [2] Gen_0011774.1       [3] 7628    [4] 5125    [5] 6931
[1] Gen_0011774.1       [2] Gen_0011774.1       [3] 7628    [4] 8838    [5] 12313
```

As you can see, the [3] column is empty, and I know the 'id in co_id' is wrong, but it was the last attempt I tried.

In other words, how can I call the associated "start" value for each gene in file1 into the new table I've made?

Edit: Changed the sample data for something that should work. And if there is repeated gene names it should show all the combinations.

Comment: you haven't assigned `id`!

Comment: yeah, the id wasn't assigned for this attempt, but I don't really know how (or what) to assign, I've already tried with 'id = co_id' or 'id = co_id[$3]' and other things like that. I only know that it can't be inside the 'if' because it generates a failed search.

Comment: what's the join criteria between the 2 files ... gene name? file1.end=file2.start? something else?  [hard to tell from your sample awk script]; would really help if you provided a sample set of matching data from both files

Comment: Sorry about that, but yeah, the idea was to match the names for each gene. Again, sorry for the sample data, didn't saw that there were no matches.

Comment: but ... in your comment to my answer ... you mention that a gene name can show up more than once in a file; soooo, you also need to show us how to process repeated/duplicate gene names

Comment: yeah, I was editing for correct format, sorry for the delay. Now it shows how it should be when repeated. And changed the sample data for correct working of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second attempt ... based on updated question with a) reduced data set and b) additional requirement to support gene name showing up more than once in either data file.

Sample data:

```
$ cat gene.1
10  Gen_3992149.1   851 900
11  Gen_0011774.1   3899    4043
12  Gen_0011774.1   7628    7692
13  Gen_3993605.1   522 535

$ cat gene.2
Gen_3993605.1   1   602
Gen_3989779.1   691 1002
Gen_3989835.1   1   993
Gen_0011774.1   1476    1712
Gen_0011774.1   5125    6931
Gen_0011774.1   8838    12313
```

Another `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '
# process first file; use gene name and row number as indices for 2-dimensional array;
# $2=gene/name, $1=row/number, $3=start/value
FNR==NR { start[$2][$1]=$3
          next }

# process second file
{ # loop through list of first dimension indices (ie, gene names)
  for (x in start)
      # if gene name ($1) shows up as first dimension index in our array ...
      if ( $1==x)
         # loop through the associated 2nd dimension, printing the desired results
         { for (y in start[x])
               { print "[1] " x "\t" "[2] " x "\t" "[3] " start[x][y] "\t" "[4] " $2 "\t" "[5] "$3 }
         }
} ' gene.1 gene.2 | sort

[1] Gen_0011774.1       [2] Gen_0011774.1       [3] 3899        [4] 1476        [5] 1712
[1] Gen_0011774.1       [2] Gen_0011774.1       [3] 3899        [4] 5125        [5] 6931
[1] Gen_0011774.1       [2] Gen_0011774.1       [3] 3899        [4] 8838        [5] 12313
[1] Gen_0011774.1       [2] Gen_0011774.1       [3] 7628        [4] 1476        [5] 1712
[1] Gen_0011774.1       [2] Gen_0011774.1       [3] 7628        [4] 5125        [5] 6931
[1] Gen_0011774.1       [2] Gen_0011774.1       [3] 7628        [4] 8838        [5] 12313
[1] Gen_3993605.1       [2] Gen_3993605.1       [3] 522 [4] 1   [5] 602
```

NOTE: piped the results through `sort` for basic sorting; could modify the sort criteria depending on desired output

As mentioned in my previous answer: If the output needs to be displayed with fixed width columns then that could be accomplished by replacing the `print` with an appropriate `printf` format string. (Alternatively, use @karakfa's example of the `column` command.)

Comment: This worked perfectly in a first run. I'm sorry for the troubles and bad info at the beginning

Comment: may I ask what does the 'start[$2][$1]=$3' means? what's the logic used for that? EDIT: moved to the related answer

Comment: I need a unique string for an array index; gene name by itself is not unique; so I opted to add row number as part of the index, but instead of concatenating gene name with row number to create a single index value, I opted for a 2-dimensional array so that I can easily peruse both indexes of the array later: so, generally speaking: array[x][y]=value, where x=$2=gene/name, y=$1=row/number, and value=$3=start/value

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This answer is based on the original question which required I create some sample test data; original question also didn't mention that gene names could occur multiple times in either data file.

---

Some sample data:

```
$ cat gene.1
1   Gen_3989161.1   696 720
2   Gen_3989469.1   693 733
3   Gen_3989837.1   462 515
4   Gen_3990203.1   27  112
5   Gen_3990467.1   476 481
6   Gen_3991323.1   134 152
7   Gen_3991401.1   597 681
8   Gen_3991403.1   175 217
9   Gen_3991951.1   897 907
10  Gen_6899912.3   888 999

$ cat gene.2
Gen_3989161.1   1696 2720
Gen_3989469.1   1693 2733
Gen_3989837.1   1462 2515
Gen_3990203.1   127  2112
Gen_3990467.1   1476 2481
Gen_3991323.1   1134 2152
Gen_3991401.1   1597 2681
Gen_3991403.1   1175 2217
Gen_3991951.1   1897 2907
Gen_8877722.9   7777 8888
```

One `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '
# process first file ...
FNR==NR { # use gene seq name as index; store start value
          start[$2]=$3
          next }

# process second file ...
{ # if we have a start value for the current gene seq name ($1)
  if ( start[$1] != "" ) 
       # then print
       print "[1] " $1 "\t" "[2] " $1 "\t" "[3] " start[$1] "\t" "[4] " $2 "\t" "[5] "$3 
}
' gene.1 gene.2

[1] Gen_3989161.1       [2] Gen_3989161.1       [3] 696 [4] 1696        [5] 2720
[1] Gen_3989469.1       [2] Gen_3989469.1       [3] 693 [4] 1693        [5] 2733
[1] Gen_3989837.1       [2] Gen_3989837.1       [3] 462 [4] 1462        [5] 2515
[1] Gen_3990203.1       [2] Gen_3990203.1       [3] 27  [4] 127 [5] 2112
[1] Gen_3990467.1       [2] Gen_3990467.1       [3] 476 [4] 1476        [5] 2481
[1] Gen_3991323.1       [2] Gen_3991323.1       [3] 134 [4] 1134        [5] 2152
[1] Gen_3991401.1       [2] Gen_3991401.1       [3] 597 [4] 1597        [5] 2681
[1] Gen_3991403.1       [2] Gen_3991403.1       [3] 175 [4] 1175        [5] 2217
[1] Gen_3991951.1       [2] Gen_3991951.1       [3] 897 [4] 1897        [5] 2907
```

If you need the output to line up with fixed width columns, that could be accomplished by replacing the `print` with an appropriate `printf` format string ...

Comment: It works nicely, but when there is a repeated name in gene.1 file it uses the last one only.

Comment: and ... what value should be used if a gene name shows up more than once? as I've already commented,  you need to supply a set of matching test data and the expected results; and now it sounds like you also need to provide additional data/comments about what happens if/when a gene name is repeated (in file1, in file2)

Comment: yeah, edited the original data and sample so you can see the correct idea, sorry for the time loss

Answer (score 0):

since your data is already sorted in the keys, you can use `join` for joining and `awk` for formatting.  Using the data by @markp (since yours don't have any common keys)

```
$ join -12 -21 -o1.2,2.1,1.3,2.2,2.3 file1 file2                | 
  awk -v OFS="\t" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                      printf "[%d] %s", i,$i (i==NF?ORS:OFS)}'  | 
  column -ts$'\t'

[1] Gen_3989161.1  [2] Gen_3989161.1  [3] 696  [4] 1696  [5] 2720
[1] Gen_3989469.1  [2] Gen_3989469.1  [3] 693  [4] 1693  [5] 2733
[1] Gen_3989837.1  [2] Gen_3989837.1  [3] 462  [4] 1462  [5] 2515
[1] Gen_3990203.1  [2] Gen_3990203.1  [3] 27   [4] 127   [5] 2112
[1] Gen_3990467.1  [2] Gen_3990467.1  [3] 476  [4] 1476  [5] 2481
[1] Gen_3991323.1  [2] Gen_3991323.1  [3] 134  [4] 1134  [5] 2152
[1] Gen_3991401.1  [2] Gen_3991401.1  [3] 597  [4] 1597  [5] 2681
[1] Gen_3991403.1  [2] Gen_3991403.1  [3] 175  [4] 1175  [5] 2217
[1] Gen_3991951.1  [2] Gen_3991951.1  [3] 897  [4] 1897  [5] 2907
```

the final pipe to `column` is for pretty printing.  Obviously the repeat of the key twice doesn't make any sense, since they have to be equal for each row.